# Rarely get SynchronousOnlyOperation error in different GET requests which have database query in Django 3.2.6

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

Error occurs only in development server environment, cant reproduce it in local. Dev server is a docker composed environment with Django 3.2.6, python 3.7, gunicorn (for wsgi), daphne (for asgi), postgres 12, redis, celery & celery-beat inside.

Error happens in GET requests which are not supposed to have any async context.

For example, log of one of these errors:

```
gunicorn_1     | [2022-12-07 13:40:21 +0000] [24] [DEBUG] GET /api/v2/sync/groups
gunicorn_1     | Internal Server Error: /api/v2/sync/groups
gunicorn_1     | Traceback (most recent call last):
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
gunicorn_1     |     response = get_response(request)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
gunicorn_1     |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
gunicorn_1     |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
gunicorn_1     |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
gunicorn_1     |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
gunicorn_1     |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
gunicorn_1     |     raise exc
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
gunicorn_1     |     self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 414, in initial
gunicorn_1     |     self.perform_authentication(request)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
gunicorn_1     |     request.user
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 227, in user
gunicorn_1     |     self._authenticate()
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 380, in _authenticate
gunicorn_1     |     user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py", line 42, in authenticate
gunicorn_1     |     return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
gunicorn_1     |   File "/code/backend/permissions.py", line 11, in get_user
gunicorn_1     |     return super().get_user(validated_token)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py", line 115, in get_user
gunicorn_1     |     user = self.user_model.objects.get(**{api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD: user_id})
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
gunicorn_1     |     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
gunicorn_1     |     num = len(clone)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
gunicorn_1     |     self._fetch_all()
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
gunicorn_1     |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
gunicorn_1     |     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1173, in execute_sql
gunicorn_1     |     cursor = self.connection.cursor()
gunicorn_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
gunicorn_1     |     raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
gunicorn_1     | django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
gunicorn_1     | Logging exception:
gunicorn_1     | You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

, the api view looks like

```py
class GroupsView(BaseSyncView):
    queryset = GroupModel.all_objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    enter code here

class BaseSyncView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = BaseSyncSerializer  # Virtual, to override
    queryset = None  # Virtual, to override
    lookup_field = 'uuid'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list_retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

Another example, for simplification - logs pointed to line in standard drf APIView:

```py
book: BookModel = BookModel.objects.get_with_raise(uuid=uuid, deleted_at__isnull=True)
```

Book model has overriden manager

```py
class Manager(DjangoBaseManager.from_queryset(BaseQuerySet)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alive_only = kwargs.pop('alive_only', True)
        super(Manager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.alive_only:
            return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(deleted_at=None)
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)

class BaseQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def get_with_raise(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            kwargs_string = ", ".join(f"{key}={value}" for key, value in kwargs.items())
            raise EntityDoesNotExistException(reason=f'{self.model.__name__} with {kwargs_string} not found')
        except Exception as ex:
            raise InternalServerException(str(ex))
```

Any advises appreciated, thanks.

**UPD 1**

It seems the issue appears when used method

```py
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
async_to_sync(func)(data)
```

and in the same time GET request which executes sql via django orm is sent to server

**UPD 2**

Switching development environment to daphne only (without gunicor) seems to "fix" the issue. Continue investigation.

**UPD 3**

It seems that the issue appears when multiple https requests are made from the same device with the same auth info for a very short period (20-30 for 1-2 seconds)

Comment: Which worker do you use with Gunicorn?

Comment: gunicorn==20.1.0 with 4 workers is used

Comment: Default workers, sync worker class I suppose

Comment: There is no async code executed by api endpoints, but in server there is api methods that send websocket messages, for that purpose asgi daphne framework is included

Comment: Gunicorn is started in docker container with command
```gunicorn --workers=4 -c config.py server.wsgi --log-level debug```

Comment: async_to_sync is used in method which sends messages to websocket channels

```def send_all_user_channels_message_sync(self, serialized_data):
        async_to_sync(send_all_user_channels_message)(self.channels, serialized_data)```

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) project on GitHub?

Comment: It is a bit difficult as I still dont know exact part of the project causing the issue

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you access your resource by going directly to the DB, without using the ORM? Django ORM is not allowing async access. Try implementing sync_to_async in your view.

Comment: Most of the times nothing unpredictable happens - the issue occurs in rare cases; I could not reproduce it myself even once - all I have is logs and reports from testers